# Exclude some rows from main query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, group-by, rank

I want to exclude two maximum accounts from my query in each company for each year, I write the query in pl-SQL but it is very slow how can I rewrite it to perform better?

My main table includes 9195771 rows.

I appreciate if anyone can help me

```
SELECT  
    g."COMPANY", g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR", SUM(g."AMOUNT")
FROM
    accounting_attribute_con a
INNER JOIN
    dana_gl_hold_vou_row_qry_dash g ON a.code_part_value = g."ACCOUNT" 
                                    AND g."COMPANY" = a.company
WHERE
    g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR" IN ('2019', '2018')
    AND g."COMPANY" IN ('DB','DD','DC','DG','DP','DO' )
    AND accounting_attribute_value_api.get_desc(a.company, attribute, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) = 'others'
    AND g."ACCOUNTING_PERIOD" <> '13'
    AND g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR"||g."COMPANY"||g."ACCOUNT" NOT IN (SELECT FROM (SELECT SUM(g."AMOUNT"), g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR" acc_year, g."COMPANY" company, g."ACCOUNT_DESC", g."ACCOUNT" acc, RANK() OVER (partition by g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR", g."COMPANY"  ORDER BY SUM(g."AMOUNT") DESC) AS rnknumber
                                  FROM accounting_attribute_con a
                                  INNER JOIN dana_gl_hold_vou_row_qry_dash g ON a.code_part_value = g."ACCOUNT" AND g."COMPANY" = a.company
                                  WHERE g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR" IN ('2019', '2018')
                                    AND g."COMPANY" IN ('DB','DD','DE','DG','DP','DO' )
                                    AND accounting_attribute_value_api.get_desc(a.company, attribute, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE) = 'others'
                                    AND g."ACCOUNTING_PERIOD" <> '13'
                                  GROUP BY g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR" , g."COMPANY"  , g."ACCOUNT_DESC" , g."ACCOUNT") b
               WHERE 
                   rnknumber <= 2) 
GROUP BY
    g."COMPANY", g."ACCOUNTING_YEAR"
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can define the maximum accounts in a query, you can use the MINUS operator to exclude those records from the main query.

Comment: would you please explain more or write the code? because I couldn't write it with minus

Comment: Any select statement is essentially a result set.  so lets say the the query you provided specifies the main select statement of all the records.  to use MINUS you need another similar select statement that returns the same column list, but excludes the records you don't want to see.

Comment: thank you a lot, I use minus operator and it improves the performance a lot.thanks for your hint